# Table design - parent with always exactly 1 or 2 children

Tags: database-design, schema

Lets say I have the following existing tables (both with a primary key column named `Id`):

```
TableA
TableB
```

Now, I need to create a new table that groups together 1 record from `TableA` with either 1 or 2 records from `TableB`.  The relationship here is *always* either 1 or 2 records and will never change, but the order of these 2 relations does matter.  I'm calling this new table `Groups` but I can't decide on the proper way to design it.

#### Option 1 - flat

```
Groups
----------------------------
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
TableAId INT NOT NULL,
TableBId1 INT NOT NULL,
TableBId2 INT NULL
```

#### Option 2 - details table

```
Groups                         GroupDetails
----------------------------   --------------
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   GroupId INT NOT NULL,
TableAId INT NOT NULL          TableBId INT NOT NULL,
                               Sort TINYINT NOT NULL
```

**Option 1** will make it easier to retrieve records since it reduces a join, but the column `TableBId2` could potentially be null in some cases.

**Option 2** will require a join, but it's more normalized and just seems like the "proper" way to design this table.

However, in this case I'm leaning towards breaking the normalization principles in favor of a slight optimization, because like I said, each `Group` record will *always* have at least 1 relation to `TableB`, and at most, a 2nd relation.  I'm struggling to make a decision on this, so I'm hoping someone can give their opinion on it.

Comment: *The relationship here is always either 1 or 2 records* Are these records equal? Can they be swapped?

Comment: No, they can't be swapped, the order of these does matter.  I've updated the question with those details.

Comment: most queries will always need to pull both records.  the relationship between the 2 records is the same, but the order of them matters, i.e. `TableBId1 = 100` and `TableBId2 = 200` is different than `TableBId1 = 200` and `TableBId2 = 100`.  But both option 1 and option 2 would require 3 joins.  Option 1:  `Groups -> TableB (Id1) -> TableB (Id2)` and Option 2: `Groups -> GroupDetails -> TableB`

Comment: Is EVERY record in TableA related to a Group, or do some TableA records have no Group, and therefore no relationship to TableB?

Answer (score 0):

The second option seems a bit odd. Why do you need the GroupDetails table instead of having a regular link table with 1 or 2 rows.

```
Groups                      
----------------------------
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
TableAId INT NOT NULL       
TableBId INT NOT NULL
Sort TINYINT NOT NULL
```

In any case if you don't need to support more than two links, I would choose the first option. There's nothing wrong with having a null value in a column, so that's not an issue. You also get rid of the cumbersome `sort` column, which for 2 values is pretty much overkill anyway.